# Understanding Bishop on EM for HMM's

Tags: self-study, hidden-markov-model, expectation-maximization

I'm reading page 616 of Bishop's PRML ([pdf](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/%7Ewurmd/Livros/school/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20And%20Machine%20Learning%20-%20Springer%20%202006.pdf)), which introduces EM for hidden markov models with categorical hidden states and arbitrary emission distributions. Bishop defines $z_n$ as the hidden state at time $n$, $x_n$ as the corresponding observation, and $\theta$ as all the parameters. When parameters are viewed separately, he writes $\pi$ for the initial condition, $A$ for the transition probabilities, and emission distribution parameters $\phi$. All told, the log likelihood is

$$\log p(z_1|\pi) + \sum_{n=2}^N \log p(z_n|z_{n-1}, A) + \sum_{n=1}^N \log p(x_n|z_n, \phi)$$

or

$$\sum_{k=1}^K z_{1k} \log \pi_k + \sum_{n=2}^N \sum_{k=1}^K\sum_{j=1}^K z_{nk}z_{n-1,j}\log A_{jk} + \sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{k=1}^K z_{nk}\log p(x_n|\phi_k)$$.

Bishop then defines two functions:

$$\gamma(z_n) = p(z_n | X, \theta)$$

$$\xi(z_n, z_{n-1}) = p(z_n, z_{n-1} | X, \theta)$$

These are a length-K vector and a K by K matrix, where $K$ is the size of the state space. Some people might prefer to notate them as $\gamma_n$ and $\xi_{n}$ because they depend on $n$, but they don't really depend on any realization of $z$.

#### The confusing part

Bishop then introduces these.

$$\gamma(z_{nk}) = E[z_{nk}] = \sum_{z_n} \gamma(z) z_{nk} $$
$$\xi(z_{nk}, z_{n-1,j}) = E[z_{nk}z_{n-1,j}] = \sum_{z_n, z_n-1} \gamma(z) z_{nk}z_{n-1,j} $$

The summations lack an index, as $\sum_0^9 i$, but I can't fill in the missing piece (the $_{i=}$).

- I would guess it is $_{z=}$, but then both lines equate scalars (left, middle) with a length-K vector (right). The text is very explicit about which ones are scalars, vectors, and matrices. Also, for the top line, the sum is over only one term, as in $\sum_{i=3.1415926535} i$, which begs the question of why it is included.
- The top RHS works much better if it's read as $\sum_k{[\gamma(z_n)]_k z_{nk}}$, but that's nonsense because the sum is not taken over the variable masquerading as the index. It's similar to writing $\sum_{i=1}v_{ij}w_j$ when you mean $\sum_j v_{1j}w_j$. It's also unclear how to generalize this strange reading to the second equation.

What's going on here? I'm lost & frustrated. Thanks!

Comment: I'll have a closer look later, but one thing to note - pi is not the value of pi, it's the vector of probabilities - see equation 13.8

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my version the summation notation is slightly different; it has
$$γ(z_{nk})=E[z_{nk}]=\sum_{\textbf{z}}γ(\textbf{z})z_{nk}$$

and the same for the second equation - it's over $\textbf{z}$.
I started off assuming $\textbf{z}$ is implying $\textbf{z}_n$ - remembering that each $\textbf{z}_n$ is a K-dimensional binary variable.

This doesn't make sense to me, because the summation of the probabilities should equal one. $z_{nk}$ should be 1 or 0, but from the text I was assuming it should be 1. Which leaves us with $\gamma(z_{nk}) = 1$, which is clearly wrong.

The other options are that $\textbf{z} = \textbf{Z}$, but that makes less sense to me, or that it's somehow implying that it should be the probability of $z_{nk} = 1$ conditioned on all the previous latent variables, but I can't see how.

I'll note finally that he brings $\gamma(z_{nk})$ back in section 13.2.2 with the phrase 'Let us begin by evaluating $\gamma(z_{nk})$', and then proceeds to evaluate $\gamma(\textbf{z}_{n})$. So I'm confused too.

Posting this as an answer instead of a comment 'cos it's easier to write the maths, and also intending to update it once I can ponder some more. If you have any insight in the meantime, please let me know...

Comment: Bishop's phrase "K-dimensional binary variable" makes it seem like he's talking about $K$ coin-flips, but from the context, it's obvious that he's talking about one roll of a die, not six flips of a coin.

Comment: I'm going to switch to a different reference and hope there's a better-explained analog of Bishop's $\xi$ and $\gamma$. Every time I open this textbook I regret it.

Comment: Yup, it's one roll of a die, but it's over a k-dimensional binary variable, where only one of the dimensions can take the value of one... the form of that is way back in chapter 2.2. I learned heaps from this textbook, but it's been hard work; definitely easier-to-understand resources around

Answer (score 0):

Considering how these quantities are used to derive EM updates, these equations seem to be wrong in multiple ways, and the corrected versions would probably read:

$$\gamma(z_{nk}) = E[z_{nk}] =  \gamma(z_n)_k  $$
$$\xi(z_{nk}, z_{n-1,j}) = E[z_{nk}z_{n-1,j}] = \xi(z_n, z_{n-1})_{k,j}$$

This is closest to the second option in the question. As support for this claim, note that Bishop often writes $\sum_{z_n} f(z_n)$ to mean $\sum_{k=1}^K f(z_n=k)$, for example in 13.36 and 13.38. Allowing for this, his notation almost works, because when $z_{n}=k$, $z_{nk}=1$ and $z_n$'s other entries are 0. The bottom equation still doesn't work, but the top equation does.